# Multiple users use linux pc at the same time

Tags: login, multiple-users

I have a powerful linux PC. Is it possible that more than one user use that PC at the same time while I will use it physically and others will use it remotely (each person will have different user and see different screen)? Can they login remotely anytime when my PC is turned on?

For example:
Suppose there are three users named `X`, `Y`, `Z` in my linux PC. I am user `X` and using the computer physically. I want that user `Y` and `Z` can login to the PC remotely at the same time and log out. They should be allowed to login to their users at any time they want. We all will use GUI.

If this is possible, please tell me how can I do that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it's possible.

Look into installing a RDP or VNC server on the Linux machine, and a RDP/VNC client (for instance [FreeRDP](https://www.freerdp.com/) or [RealVNC](https://www.realvnc.com/en/)) on the users' computers.

RDP ([Remote Desktop Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol)) and VNC ([Virtual Network Computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing)) both are technologies that enable remote graphical use of another computer.

In addition to logging in with a graphical interface, users can also login to a terminal using [SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell).

Comment: It would be nice if `ssh -X` was mentioned here as well (X11 forwarding via ssh). This is how I use my virtual machines most of the time. I can do remote emacs without any RDP or VNC stuff. Sidenote: While still on Windows, I used that also for WSL.

Answer (score 3):

Install xrdp with the following command,

```
sudo apt install xrdp
```

Enable and start it

```
sudo systemctl enable xrdp --now
sudo systemctl start xrdp
```

Make sure it is running

```
sudo systemctl status xrdp
```

Now all user accounts on the Linux PC can remote desktop using the building RDP client on Windows and Remmina on Linux.

The username and password are the same as their credentials on Linux PC.